# Graph Theory problem about Regular Graphs. [1]

Tags: graph-theory

**Problem:** Let $G$ be a graph of order $n$ in which every vertex has degree equal to $d.$

1. How large must $d$ be in order to guarantee that $G$ is connected?
2. How large must $d$ be in order to guarantee that $G$ is $2-$ connected?

**My Attempt:**

i. By the Handshaking lemma $$\frac{nd}{2}=e\geq n-1.\implies d\geq \frac{2(n-1)}{n}.$$ However the answer is $$\lceil\frac{n-1}{2}\rceil.$$ I am not sure as to what reasoning was employed to come up with this solution.

ii. A graph is said to be $2$-connected if for every vertex $v\in V(G)$ the graph $G-v$ is connected. For this part, I am not even sure as to how should proceed.

Any hints/suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Your answer by the handshake lemma implies that $d$ *needs* to be at least $\frac{2(n-1)}{n}$ (which means at least $2$) for the graph to be connected: otherwise you won't have the necessary $n-1$ edges.

But even if $d$ is that large, it's still possible to get a disconnected graph. For example, when $n=10$, you can go up to $d=4$ and still be disconnected:

[image: 2 copies of K5]

You can generalize this construction:

- When $n$ is even, take two complete graphs on $\frac n2$ vertices; this is regular with degree $\frac n2 -1$.
- When $n$ is odd, take a complete graph on $\frac{n-1}{2}$ vertices, and a complete-graph-without-a-perfect-matching on $\frac{n+1}{2}$ vertices; this is regular with degree $\frac{n-1}{2}-1$.

The content of part 1 of the problem is that you can't do better than these two examples: as soon as you're regular with degree $\frac{n-1}{2}$ (when $n$ is odd) or $\frac n2$ (when $n$ is even), you're connected.

We can prove this by contradiction. Suppose the graph is not connected; then it has $2$ components (at least) with no edges between them. One of them has size at most $\frac n2$, and the degrees in that component can be at most $\frac{n}{2}-1 < \frac{n-1}{2}$.

---

Part 2 of the problem can be solved similarly. Suppose that $G$ is $d$-regular and connected but not $2$-connected. Then there is a vertex $v$ we can remove to get two components.

The smallest component has size $k$, $k \le \lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor$. In that component of $G-v$, all degrees are at most $k-1$, so in $G$ the degrees are at most $k$. In fact, even in $G$, one of those degrees must be $k-1$: the vertex $v$ would have too high degree if it were adjacent to every vertex of the component of size $k$, and a vertex of every other component. So if $G$ is not $2$-connected, we have $d \le \lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor - 1$. In other words, if $d \ge \lfloor \frac{n-1}{2} \rfloor$ and connected, then $G$ is $2$-connected.

Comment: How did you prove that $d$ must be at least $\lceil\frac{n-1}{2}\rceil?$

Comment: If it isn't, then the counterexamples that I mentioned are possible. (They only explicitly rule out $d = \frac n2 - 1$ and $d = \frac{n-1}{2}-1$, but we could replace the complete graphs by lower-degree regular graphs on the same vertex set to rule out smaller $d$.)

Comment: Thank you. I understood this part. Any ideas on how I should go about the second part?

Comment: Apply part 1 of the problem to the graph you get when you remove any vertex of $G$. (More or less. The graph $G-v$ is not $d$-regular, but similar considerations apply.)

Comment: If $n$ is odd we could split the graph $G-v$ into two components both with $(n-1)/2$ vertices, right?

Comment: If that happened, it would mean that $G$ is not $2$-connected. But it can only happen if $d \le \frac{n-1}{2}$ or so. (Why?)

Comment: Another approach is to use [Dirac's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac%27s_theorem_on_Hamiltonian_cycles).

Comment: Could you please give an answer, if you have some time. I would be really grateful.